# Using Map.get() method in typescript, returns undefined, while I am handling undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, hashmap

I am trying to map the repetition of letters into a hashmap and then returning the first non-repeated character in a string. Following is the function I've written to do so:

```js
export const firstNonRepeatedFinder = (aString: string): string | null => {
  const lettersMap: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

  for (let letter of aString) {
    if (!lettersMap.has(letter)) {
      lettersMap.set(letter, 1);
    } else {
      incrementLetterCount(letter, lettersMap);
    }
  }

  for (let letter of aString) {
    if (lettersMap.get(letter) === 1) return letter;
  }

  return null;

  function incrementLetterCount(
    aLetter: string,
    aLettersHashMap: Map<string, number>
  ): void {
    if (
      aLettersHashMap.has(aLetter) &&
      aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter) !== undefined
    ) {
      aLettersHashMap.set(aLetter, aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter) + 1);
    }
  }
};
```

However, in `incrementLetterCount`, function, although I am handling to exclude the `undefined` values for getting a `key` in the hashmap, it still complaining about `Object is possibly 'undefined'` which means that the `get` method is might return undefined and I cannot proceed with it.

Does anyone know what I am missing here that results in this error?

Comment: That's weird, but does `if (aLettersHashMap.has(aLetter) && aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter))` work? Just test its truthiness.

Comment: Then again it also seems like you're missing the `else { aLettersHashMap.set(aLetter, 1); }` case that should do the initialization.

Comment: @cs95 yes, `if (aLettersHashMap.has(aLetter) && aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter))` is true.

I am not sure if I fully understood the second comment. But do you mean that in the else statement I should have instantiated `{ aLettersHashMap.set(aLetter, 1); }`?

in more details:
`else {
      lettersMap.set(letter, 1);
      incrementLetterCount(letter, lettersMap);
    }
`

if so, this will always default the `aLetter` counter to 1

Comment: @cs95 just another update:
even `aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter)` has a value of `1` when I console.log() it in the incrementation loop, before incrementing it, meaning that they are instantiated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem but still not sure why the original code snippet was throwing a compile-time error (although the code was checking against `undefined` values).

It seems that in Typescript we can assert that the operand is not `null/undefined` (from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)).

> A new `!` post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded.

```js
  function incrementLetterCount(
    aLetter: string,
    aLettersHashMap: Map<string, number>
  ): void {
      aLettersHashMap.set(aLetter, aLettersHashMap.get(aLetter)! + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

Another reason is the tsconfig.json might have the following settings

"strict": true,       /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

if you take out the line, the error should go away.